# Многошаговая форма после рестарта запоминает шаг и данные

Tags: javascript, php, html, form

Как реализовать многошаговую форму регистрации,в которой после закрытия и возрате к ней, запоминается шаг и данные формы. 
Технологии JS/PHP

Comment: если кратко - то изучите js или php на выбор.

Comment: Ваш ответ никать не раскрывает суть вопроса, никаких рекомендаций Вы дать не способны?

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий)

Comment: @AndreySmolin вариант с пошаговой формой несложен, сложнее придумать как запоминать данные. Например, у Вас имеется форма как у гугла. Пользователь вводит логин(записываете в куки), ввёл пароль - взяли логин и отправили форму на сервер, если успешно очистили куки. Так и на странице с формой проверяешь есть ли логин в куках и выводишь соответственную форму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea');

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  (function(element) {
    var id = element.getAttribute('id');
    element.value = localStorage.getItem(id);//атрибут id обязателен
    element.oninput = function() {
      localStorage.setItem(id, element.value);
    };
  })(elements[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie - вот что вам нужно. Технологии JS/PHP имеют функции cookie => выбирайте что вам по душе.

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать на js, для этого можно воспользоватся замечатльным **localStorage**

На каждом этапе собираете данные полей форм, записываете эти данные в объект, например:

```
//Объект
let formData = {
   userName: input1.value,
   userAge: input2.value
};
// и тд
```

А дальше для удобного хранения преобразуем все это дело в **JSON**

```
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(formData);
```

Ну а дальше просто заносим этот JSON в localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', jsonData);
```

В нужный момент достаем эти данные и расставляем по нужным инпутам

```
let storageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
```

Это лишь пример, и все можно сделать лучше, но думаю суть вы поняли.